# I have some jquery and css striping (animate) on my my data rows after they are populated

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

They look like this before any click:

[image: Before any click has occurred]

When you click on Sales in the business area a drop down select box appears. If I was do click on "Sales" and make a change to that text area it would animate to grey. The grey rows animate to grey as well which is fine, but the black rows should fade to black and not grey.

After selection has been made:

[image]

Notice I changed Sales to property and after the animate() function it is grey and screwed up the striping now.

Here's my function:

```
success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        //change the verbiage of the ".look" element to the newly-changed value of the ".touch" element
                        theLook.text(newDes);

                        //swap out the elements so it looks like a normal table cell again
                        back_to_look();

                        //flash the span it's in so the user knows the change was successful
                        theTd.css('background-color','#59b4d4').animate({ backgroundColor: "#333333" }, 1500);
                    } else {
                        //flash the ".touch" element in red but DO NOT flip back to the ".look" element since there was a problem updating the data
                        var oldColor = theTouch.css('background-color');
                        theTouch.css('background-color','#ff0000').animate({ backgroundColor: oldColor }, 1500);
```

How do I determine the original background color setting, and return
it to that? Do I have to target the css using the jquery css() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
theTd.css('background-color','#59b4d4').animate({ backgroundColor: "#333333" }, 1500);
```

Is changing the bg color back to #333333 once it's done with the flash (highlight).. Try this:

```
var currentColor = theTd.css('backgroundColor');
theTd.css('background-color','#59b4d4').animate({ backgroundColor: currentColor }, 1500);
```

So, instead of assigning the backgroundColor: #333333 in the animate as before we create a variable called currentColor and pull the current background color from the table cell we're about to edit.

This way, once we edit the table cell we know which color it needs to go back to. You can see in the second line above instead of setting it back to #333333 we set it to our new variable currentColor.

Comment: That worked brilliantly. Thank you so much, want to go into more depth of what's going on here?

Comment: Added some more detail to the answer for clarification. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To determinte background color just go with:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function () {
    var x = $(this).css('background-color');
    hexColor(x);
    alert(color);
});

function hexColor(colorValue) {
    var parts = colorValue.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i], 10).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/UwUat/)